# Token input library in angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I have used jQuery plugin token input for generation results as shown in the image in the asp.net core

But I want a plugin or library for angular. can you please suggest any angular 12 libraries that will perform the same functionality as the jQuery plugin.
token input [generated custom fields like FN LN when search results are shown as shown in the image ]

[image]

I tried  input field  angular library but not supported.

Comment: angular uses javascript not C# why do you have the C# tag here?

Comment: Why can't you just use jquery with angular?  What is the name of the plugin you are using for jquery that is doing the functionality you want?

Comment: token-input plugin of jQuery